# Deploy containerized Angular application to ECS Fargate

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an Express JS Angular application that I am deploying to ECS Fargate. The application has a couple of `process.env.ENVS` that I need to pass into the application code through the Docker container. Initially I thought I can use `envsubst` to pass in these variables into the JS files that are using the variables, but it turns out after the container is created the values do not get read in appropriately. I then discovered there is a certain method of passing in environment variables to a containerized application. This method also uses `nginx` to host the application. I followed this [tutorial](https://pumpingco.de/blog/environment-variables-angular-docker/). Below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecr/base:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

The problem I'm having is in Fargate after the container deploys I am getting the following error in the logs:

```
2023/02/13 16:39:31 [error] 9#9: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.env" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.18.0.58, server: localhost, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

It's saying a `.env` file does not exist in the nginx directory. That is correct that a `.env` does not exist. It is supposed to be looking for either `env.template.js` or `env.js` depending on where in the `envsubst` command it is in.

Any ideas where I went wrong would be appreciated. Please let me know if anything is missing from this post that is needed. Thanks!

Comment: `envsubst` command is trying to substitute the contents of an environment file named `.env` into the `/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js` file, but it's unclear where the `.env` file is supposed to come from.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the contents of the env.template.js file into an env.js file, you should modify the Dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
FROM xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecr/base:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Comment: The contents are going into env.js file. I should substitute into a .env file instead of env.js file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Dockerfile you submitted, the envsubst command is performing the following task: it reads `env.template.js` and outputs the result to `/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js`

However, the error message in the logs suggests that your application is attempting to access the file `/.env`. This discrepancy between the expected file and the file being accessed by the application is the root cause of the issue.

To resolve the problem, you have two options:

Modify the logic of your application so that it loads the correct file, i.e. `/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js`.
Change the file that `envsubst` is redirecting its output to so that it matches the file being accessed by your application, i.e `/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/.env`.